# What tools can be used to moderate public Slack communities?

Tags: moderators, chat-rooms

[Slack](https://slack.com/) is beginning to pick up a lot of growth in places where it wasn't originally intended. While it's focused on teams in the workplace, it seems to be becoming popular with many public online communities. Places like [Slacklist](http://www.slacklist.info/) and [Chit Chats](http://www.chitchats.co/) list quite a few.

How are people moderating these communities? There are probably a few good questions around this, but to stay specific: What tools are people using? The built-in moderation tools seem to be fairly lacking if you aren't already working with a trusted group.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to identify when conversations violate your terms of use around the type of content allowed, i.e. adult content or images, then you could utilize the webhooks that Slack provides and pass the content through Content Moderator's API (http://www.microsoft.com/moderator) which will alert you when flags are raised.